# Can a silverlight application open a socket (TCP/IP) connection to the same server or another server?

Tags: silverlight, sockets, tcp

I want to develop a Silverlight application that opens a dedicated TCP/IP connection to the server that it is run from. What are the restrictions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only restriction in this scenario is that the port number you are connecting to must be in the range of 4502-4534.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Where these numbers come from (Post numbers). Any refrence?

Comment: @user654019: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296248(v=VS.95).aspx  see final paragraph under "Networking Protocol Support" section.